# Background not blur activity in ICS api level 14 when open dialog in android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-alertdialog, android-2.3-gingerbread

I making apps for background image blur when open dialog on button click event and its working for api level 8(Gingerbread) and api level 14 (ICS) not background image blur its only dimming background like on light black, what i do,
Thanks for in Advance

This is code working on Android 2.3 and 4.0 not working,

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
    lp.dimAmount=0.0f;  
    alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
    alertDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);  
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: This flag is deprecated and should not be used since it is not supported anymore.

Comment: Alternate solution for in used for ICS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` was deprecated in API level 14.

> Blurring is no longer supported.

As per *Dianne Hackborn* Android framework engineer

> I recommend avoiding this.  Back in the G1 days the blur effect could
>   be implemented somewhat efficiently in software.  Those days are long
>   past.  This is something you should avoid until at some point in the
>   future when it is done on the GPU.

Comment: Try FLAG_DIM_BEHIND.. There is no alternative though.

Comment: FLAG_DIM_BEHIND this flag i already used and its for only dim like on black background and it is default dialog background.

Answer (score 0):

`FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` is deprecated at API Level 14 that's why it works on 2.3 and not on 4.0